# How can I animate a line drawing using SVG?

Tags: html, svg, path

I'm trying to run this https://jsfiddle.net/kfbzhy9p/ as one continuous line but it breaks into two and doesn't seem to connect.  If I stop the animation it's only partly drawn.  I'm saving the path using illustrator and `object >> compound path >> make`  Could this be the [stroke-miterlimit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-miterlimit) attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path is approximately 1908 units long, that's why treating it as something 1000 units long makes things look odd.

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: s/1000/1908/g in your CSS

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kfbzhy9p/1/ i shrank the size in illustrator and that did it

Comment: do u mind explaining what `s/1000/1908/g ` means to me.  I assume it's an adjustment of the global size.

Comment: globally (the g) search (the s) for 1000 and replace it by 1908 (e.g. http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/vi-vim-faq-how-replace-tab-character-space-spaces)